# How can I access the created date from firebase token for a user?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

How can I access created on from the userRecord object  for a firebase user? What are the other details that can be accessed using uid/email? (using python)

I tried the following code and able to retrieve the uid.

```
user_obj = auth.get_user_by_email(email) 
uid=user_obj.uid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When signing up with firebase's password based auth, you are provided with email, password and other meta data. You can get `creation_timestamp` from metadata  See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#firebase_admin.auth.UserMetadata
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#firebase_admin.auth.UserRecord

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on [`get_user_by_email`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#firebase_admin.auth.get_user_by_email) it seems that it returns a [`UserRecord` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#firebase_admin.auth.UserRecord). This in turn contains a `user_metadata` property that has a [`creation_timestamp` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#firebase_admin.auth.UserMetadata).

So:

```
user_obj.user_metadata.creation_timestamp
```